# Vue 2 app can't lazy load routes import componentes in vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm trying to lazy load routes in a Vue 2 application following the guides but webpack is not creating the chunks.

In my router file

```
const Home = () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Home" */'@/features/titles/views/Home.vue');
```

My vue config's file is already removing the prefetch - and preload - plugin (as [suggested here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/lazy-route-gets-prefetched-ignoring-webpack-magic-comments/94667))

```
config.plugins.delete('prefetch');
```

but the output from the build task is always the same:

```
File           Size                                                                              Gzipped

  dist/app.js    2024.66 KiB                                                                       452.42 KiB
```

The vue version is 2.6.1 and vue-router, 3.0.7.
The project has Typescript set up and I don't know f there is any relation, because in others similars projects with plain js, the lazy load in routes works fine.
Anyone has any ideia of what could be wrong in the implementation/configuration?

Comment: Can you show us your whole router.ts file please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different config, something like this:

```js
module.exports =
{
  configureWebpack: (config) =>
  {
    config.optimization = {
      // runtimeChunk: 'single',
      moduleIds: 'hashed',
      splitChunks:
      {
        automaticNameDelimiter: '_',
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: 5,
        minSize: 5000,
        // maxSize: 250000,
        cacheGroups:
        {
          default:
          {
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -20,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
          },
          vendor:
          {
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name(module)
            {
              // get the name. E.g. node_modules/packageName/not/this/part.js
              // or node_modules/packageName
              const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];

              // npm package names are URL-safe, but some servers don't like @ symbols
              return `vendors_${packageName.replace('@', '')}`;
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };
  },
  chainWebpack: config =>
  {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false);
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development')
    {
      config.module.rule('eslint').use('eslint-loader').loader('eslint-loader').tap(options =>
      {
        delete options.cacheIdentifier;
        options.cache = false; // otherwise on each restart cached errors won't be shown !!!
        return options;
      });
    }
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').loader('vue-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      delete options.cacheDirectory;
      return options;
    });
    config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.plugins.delete('prefetch'); // for async routes
    config.plugins.delete('preload'); // for CSS

    // condense whitespace in templates
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      options.compilerOptions = { whitespace: 'condense' };
      return options;
    });

    return config;
  }
};
```